# From/In his experience, a case like this usually entails ill intention - "from" or "in"?

Tags: prepositions, usage

**Example 1**

> **From/In** his experience, a case like this usually entails ill intention.

**Example 2**

> **From/In** my father's experience, my brother must have skipped the class.

Answer (score 1):

As this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=In%20my%20experience%20it%2CFrom%20my%20experience%20it&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows, both forms are used, but the IN form is most common at the start of a sentence. Here are examples:

> In his experience it had been aggressive competition and investment that had converted past challenges into profitable opportunities for his company, and he reaffirmed his belief that they also held the key to the future - *The challenge of change: Arthur Menzies Johnson(1983)*

> From his experience in therapy he observed individuals struggling to develop and wrestling with decisions which ultimately they succeeded in making. - *Carl Rogers: Brian Thorne, ‎Pete Sanders (2012)*

Note that the phrase "In his experience" is normally used in relation to an overall opinion of a situation, rather than to a specific example of it. Your first example makes sense, because the word "usually" implies a general opinion, but the second example is not correct because it relates to just one class, which is quite specific.

Comment: I've never used _START_ in an NGram, but it seems to me the preference for ***In** my experience* is far stronger in [my chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=In+my+experience+it%2CFrom+my+experience+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), so I think yours must be picking up a lot of contextually irrelevant matches, because the more extreme usage split better matches my personal perception.

Comment: @fumblefingers  I added __START__ to eliminate sentences containing things like ".... learned from my experience...".  I agree that adding **it** is probably a better solution to the problem, so I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

In my dialect (which is fairly close to standard European English), the two expressions are much more different in structure than the question seems to suggest. In particular, it's NOT the case that one is simply a less common variant of the other!

**The context in which they're used**

"From [my] experience ..." is more likely to be used when you're indicating specific lessons from a particular domain of (often, but not always, professional or vocational) activity whereas "In my experience ..." tends to be used more widely for lessons about anything in life or anyone you might meet.

- **Grammar-related differences**

With "From [my/your/her/their] experience ...", the subject of the main clause is very often the person who has acquired the experience (this isn't absolutely always true -- one can learn from someone else's experience -- but it's a fairly good rule of thumb). With "In my/your/our experience ...", there's more freedom.

So:

```
- From [my] experience, I'd say* you should wipe the surface with alcohol before applying the treatment.
```

and

```
- In my experience, you'll get better results if you wipe the surface with alcohol first.
```

BUT

With "In my experience ...", the tense will most likely be a present,
present perfect or some form of conditional, as it's usually used to
express general rules or observations.
Thus:

```
- In my experience, Johnnie's always been good fun.
- Does that paint wear well in harsh climates in your experience?
- In our experience, you must wait a few minutes before applying the patch.
```

**Your examples revisited**

To come back to your examples:

```
- In his experience, a case like this usually entails ill intention.
```

or

```
- From [his] experience, he knows* a case like this usually entails ill intention.
```

...

```
- In my father's experience, my brother has a tendency to skip class.
- From [my father's] experience, he realises* my brother has probably skipped the class.
```

Your second example doesn't sound right (at least to me) because the main clause is not a general rule or observation.

In both cases you can add adjectives like these fairly liberally before the word "experience": "extensive", "broad", "long", "limited", "bitter", "painful", etc. ... or even "long years of" and similar.

**Conclusion and a little P.S.**

The two expressions are quite different. One of the big differences is that with "From [my] experience ...", the possessive adjective or nominal adjectival phrase in the middle is unnecessary: "From experience ..." is just as good as (say) "From her experience ...".

..........................................................................................................................................

/* In informal contexts you could get away without the "I'd say"/"he knows"/"he realises" in the examples marked with an asterisk, as long as the context makes it obvious whose thinking you're referring to.